# Iphone Alert Box Like Volume Buttons

Tags: iphone

i would like to create a message box similar to which appears when the volume buttons are pressed. 
[image: box]

Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the MBProgressHUD project:
https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD
http://blog.elucidcode.com/2011/03/using-a-hud-to-display-alerts-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your own `UIView` based on your needs. You can reduce `alpha` content for the view to get the transparent effect. You can add anything to your view.